# Filter database table with Powershell

Tags: database, powershell, powershell-3.0, where-clause

I am currently trieng to work with data which I got from a database table. The table has the columns "Active" and "Component". My goal is to get all components, which are disabled (value "N").

I thought the Where - Statement would be the right way to go, but the following code also has active components in it:

```
$Table.COMPONENT| Where {$Table.ACTIVE -eq "N"}
```

The table variable is already filled with data from the database.

Comment: What datatype is `$table`? you can see this with `$table.gettype()` . I guess something like that `$Table | where {$_.active -eq "N"}` should work

Comment: Try `$Table | Where-Object {$_.Active -eq "N"} | Select-Object -Property Component`.

Comment: `($Table | Where-Object Active -eq 'N').Component`

Comment: @guiwhatsthat - the type of `$table` is irrelevant; presumably, the querent knows that it contains two member properties of interest, "Active" and "Component", that "Active" will have the values "Y" and "N", and any other info is superfluous.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin - Thank you (and all the others) for your help. I am not yet 100% sure that it works, but as far as I can tell now it seems to work!  :)